# cancelling out of bootstrap's noclose class

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following list, which thanks to the bootstrap `noclose` class, will not close until I've clicked outside of the drop-down, so the user selects as many options as they want with `<ul class="dropdown-menu noclose">`

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button id ="seButton" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-placeholder="Options">Options<span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu noclose">    
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ex3_1" name="ex3[]" value="A">
      <label for="ex3_1">A : +/-</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ex3_2" name="ex3[]" value="B">
      <label for="ex3_2">B : +/-</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <c..d...e...f...g...etc...>
    </li>        
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li style="text-align: center;"> <button id ="submitButton" class="btn btn-success" data-placeholder="SUBMIT">SUBMIT</button> </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This was great until I decided to add a submit button inside of the dropdown list.  The button works, and all of the javascript behind it functions perfectly, but I can't figure out how to get the list to close upon clicking that submit button instead of forcing the user to click outside of the dropdown.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle the close of the dropdown using `toggle` method.

Like:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".dropdown-menu").dropdown("toggle");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  For some reason this did not work for me, but armed with the new `toggle` syntax I found this code on another SO post:  adding a fake class onto the button, then using `$(".myFakeClass").dropdown('toggle');` worked for me.